# expexted value of maximum of discrete random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I was wondering how to calculate $E[max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}]$ with $X_1,\dots, X_n$ iid and discrete uniform distributed on $[0,\vartheta]$.

Since the RV's are not continuous, I can't use $E[X]=\int_0^\vartheta 1-F(X) dx$ and using $E[max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty 1-F(i)^n$ leads to a divergent sum.

So how should I solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Better write uniform on $\{0,1,\ldots,\vartheta\}$ for discrete uniform. If you mean uniform on $[0,\vartheta]$ where $\vartheta$ is a positive integer, then this is no longer discrete uniform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume $\vartheta$ is a positive integer.  Let $Y = \max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.
For each integer $0 \le x \le \vartheta$,
$$\mathbb P(Y \le x) = \mathbb P(X_i \le x)^n = \frac{(x+1)^n}{(\vartheta+1)^n}$$
so
$$ \mathbb P(Y \ge x) = 1 - \mathbb P(Y \le x-1) = 1 - \frac{x^n}{(\vartheta+1)^n}$$
and
$$ \eqalign{\mathbb E[Y] &= \sum_{x=1}^\vartheta x \mathbb P(Y=x) \cr &= \sum_{x=1}^\vartheta \mathbb P(Y\ge x) \cr &= \vartheta - \sum_{x=1}^\vartheta \frac{x^n}{(\vartheta+1)^n}\cr  }$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but why is $P(Y\leq x)=(\frac{x+1}{\vartheta +1})^n$ ? I got $(\frac{x}{\vartheta})^n$

Comment: @Uperm Remember that $0$ is a possible value.  So there are $\vartheta+1$ possible values, of which $x+1$ are $\le x$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $\sum x \mathbb{P}(Y=x) = \sum \mathbb{P}(Y \geq x)$?

Comment: @MisterMak For random variables that take nonnegative integer values,
$$ \sum_{x = 1}^\infty \mathbb P(Y \ge x) = \sum_{x =1}^\infty \sum_{y = x}^\infty \mathbb  P(Y = y) = \sum_{y = 1}^\infty \sum_{x=1}^y \mathbb P(Y = y) =
\sum_{y=1}^\infty y \mathbb P(Y=y) $$